# Can someone explain what an imperfect authentic cadence is? What are the requirements to make this?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-progressions, cadence

I don't really fully understand what an imperfect authentic cadence is. I was told that if the chords are inverted, then it's considered an IAC. Or maybe the melody can be 4–3, etc. I just need an explanation that's easy to understand. What are the requirements to make an IAC?

Answer (score 4):

There are two opposing schools of thought. Aaron has offered one, so I'll offer the other:

In order to be an authentic cadence—perfect or imperfect—*both the V and the I **must** be in root position*. This is deduced from large-scale studies of both prolongation in tonal music as well as phrase structure. And music of the common-practice period is incredibly consistent in this regard: inverted V chords prolong tonic, whereas cadences at the ends of phrases exclusively use root-position V chords.

As such, a V<sup>6</sup>–I (an imperfect authentic cadence in the other school of thought) is best understood as just prolonging tonic. It's not until you get a root-position V that we have a true cadence.

With this out of the way, the only different between an IAC and a PAC is the soprano scale degree: in a PAC, it's scale-degree 1 in the I chord. In the IAC, it's either 3 or 5.

Comment: The "statistical" part of this is new and interesting to me. Can you point to a study or theorist I could read?

Comment: Seems much simpler over here - they're all perfect cadences! (No, not the imperfect ones - they're imperfect...)

Comment: @Aaron Sorry, I forgot about your question here. I can't remember specific research, but William Caplin and William Rothstein are two of the big names in this arena. They don't approach it "statistically" *per se*, but their corpus studies do suggest the importance of the root-position V.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put...

**Perfect authentic cadence**

- Both chords in root position, and
- Tonic in the highest voice for the final chord

**Imperfect authentic cadence**

- Everything else (meaning, chords are in root position, but final chord does not have the tonic in the highest voice; one or both chords is inverted; V chord is replaced by viio chord)

Comment: Really need a different word from 'imperfect' - which on the East of the Atlantic means pretty well the opposite.

Comment: I just want to call out, for future visitors, one point that both the question and answer are taking as understood: All "authentic cadences" move from the dominant (V) to the tonic (I). That's the most fundamental defining characteristic of "what an imperfect authentic cadence is," and a perfect as well, as opposed to half or plagal.